# jQuery Cycle & jTweetsAnywhere together

Tags: jquery, cycle

I want to use [jTweetsAnywhere](http://thomasbillenstein.com/jTweetsAnywhere/) to show my latest tweets, then I like to use [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) to cycle through the tweets one by one. The problem seems to be that the markup from jTweetsAnywhere needs to be loaded before jQuery Cycle loads or jQuery Cycle wont work.

jTweetsAnywhere:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#latest-tweets').jTweetsAnywhere({
        username: 'Twittername',
        count: 5,
    });
});
```

jQuery cycle:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#latest-tweets ul').cycle({
        fx: "scrollDown",
        easing: "easeOutCubic",
        speed: 600,
        timeout: 5000
    });
});
```

How do I get the markup for the tweets to load before jQuery cycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pushed an update to the  [jTweetsAnywhere github repo](https://github.com/tbillenstein/jTweetsAnywhere). The plugin now supports two new event handlers that were called when the tweet feed gets populated.

The **onReadyHandler** is called exactly once after the tweets are initially loaded
and added to the DOM. Immediately after calling this event handler the
onFeedPopulationHandler is called with the invocations parameter set to
0.

The **onFeedPopulationHandler** is called each time new tweets were added
to the tweet feed - and thereby to the DOM. The supplied event handler
should have the following interface: function(invocations, options) {}
The invocations parameter contains the present # of calls to the
handler, starting at 0 for the first call. This event handler is called
either for populating the feed by paging or by autorefreshing.

Sample:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#jta_testfeed').jTweetsAnywhere(
    {
        searchParams: 'q=html5',
        count: 5,

        parts: ['connect-button', 'login-info', 'tweet-box', 'tweets'],

        showTweetFeed:
        {
            autoConformToTwitterStyleguide: true,
            showProfileImages: true,

            paging:
            {
                mode: 'more'
            },
            autorefresh: 
            {
                mode: 'trigger-insert',
                interval: 30
            },
            showTimestamp:
            {
                refreshInterval: 10
            }
        },
        onReadyHandler: function()
        {
            if (console)
            {
                console.log('onReadyHandler: # of children = ' + $('.jta-tweet-list').children().length);
            }
        },
        onFeedPopulationHandler: function(invocations)
        {
            if (console)
            {
                console.log('onFeedPopulationHandler: invocations: ' + invocations + ', # of children = ' + $('.jta-tweet-list').children().length);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to see if your plugin has a callback for completion and start slides from there. Check plugin docs/API

Answer (score 0):

If there is no callback, you could try using [timer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval#Example) to check if tweets markup has been loaded and then initialise jQuery Cycle

**Pseudocode**

```
var intervalID; 
intervalID = setInterval(initJQueryCyle, 500); // Half second
function initJQueryCycle(){
  // Check DOM here
  if ($('#latest-tweets li').length === 5)
  {
    // Stop timer
    clearInterval(intervalID);

    // initialiseJQueryCycle here
    $('#latest-tweets ul').cycle(options);        
  }
}
```

Comment: May I ask you to elaborate? How do I initiate jquery cycle? Can't get it to work.